# Why is there an error with gfortran but ifort and pgf90 do not?

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran

I'm trying to install a package called [ESL-bundle](https://gitlab.com/ElectronicStructureLibrary/esl-bundle/-/tree/master). One of its modules (called futile) went wrong when I tried to change the compiler.

my operation:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/ElectronicStructureLibrary/esl-bundle/-/tree/master
mkdir install && cd install
#export FC=<path of gfortran> # using pgf90 by default
../esl-bundle/install-bundle --conditions +yaml futile | tee ./install-1.log
```

I can use pgf90 and ifort to compile it, but gfortran gives the error:

```
esl-bundle/checkouts/futile-1.8/dicts/f_precisions.f90:95:29:

   95 |       k=int(f_loc(a(2))-f_loc(a(1)))
      |                             1
Error: Type mismatch in argument ‘routine’ at (1); passed REAL(4) to UNKNOWN
```

There are some functions calculating the size of some types:

```
    function sizeof_r(av) result(k)
      !function documented here
      implicit none
      real(f_simple), intent(in) :: av
      real(f_simple), dimension(2) :: a
      integer :: k
      a(1)=av
         k = int(f_loc(a(2)) - f_loc(a(1)))
    end function sizeof_r
```

The definition of f_loc():

```
!> Function which identifies the address of the scalar object
!! associated to a unknown quantity
function f_loc(routine)
  use f_precisions, only: f_address
  implicit none
  external :: routine       !< Object
  integer(f_address) :: f_loc  !< Address of the object routine

  call getlongaddress(routine,f_loc)

end function f_loc
```

It seems that 'routine' don't have a type which causes problems.

So why pgf90 and ifort could handle this but gfortran couldn't? Can I fix it with some compiler flags?

I want to compile it with gfortran, since my program is mainly based on it.

Update:
This bundle is quite old and widely used in many scientific software, so I don't want to debug or rewrite any part of it (though it seems ridiculous in today's views).

Comment: Where does this `getlongaddress` come from? What argument declarations does it use? I suppose it is to get addresses of functions and subroutines. The `routine` argument is a procedure argument. Using it for scalar variables is horrible abuse. There are standard routines for getting addresses of objects available. Or widely available extensions like `loc()`.

Comment: `routine` doesn't have a type because it's been declared as a dummy subroutine. `a(1)` is a real scalar, and it's rather unfair to expect gfortran to compie such broken code, compiler flags or no. For support with broken third-party code, you are better talking to the software vendor.

Comment: Regardless, if you are trying to get the difference between the address of two consecutive elements of an array, there's the intrinsic `storage_size`.

Comment: *Can I fix it with some compiler flags?* You can try `-fallow-argument-mismatch` but be aware that what the code is going is highly dubious and completely illegal. Even in C function pointers are **NOT** compatible with normal data `void *` pointers. There is no guarantee that data pointers and function pointers even have the same size on an arbitrary architecture.

Comment: A quick patch to fix a clear bodge could easilly be less work than trying to come up how to compile the illegal code for days. You can try to separate the subroutone definition from the call so that the compiler does not see it, but it is not any less work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use the flag -fallow-argumnet-mismatch to avoid this error. And I find this flag used in its mpi version (using mpiifort and mpicc). So I guess it's a common operation in this program.

I believe there are better ways to calculate the size of types, but considering the programmers' actual job (99% scientists) and the times they wrote this program, I think there's no need to care about its internal implementation.